Is there an API that returns a swap transaction on Raydium using mint addresses and parameters like amountIn and minAmountOut?
Looking for an API that can generate a swap transaction on Raydium Liquidity V4 using token mint addresses, with parameters like amountIn and minAmountOut. Does anyone know of an available API that supports this functionality? Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
